# Powershell Posted object always null when calling rest API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am posting a json in a Powershell build step in Azure DevOps 2019 (onpremise) to an ASP.net Core API in the following way:

```
    $JSON = @'
    {
        "id":13,
        "parameter1":34,
        "parameter2":"sometext",
        "parameter3":1232      
    }
    '@

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://myapi/queue/" -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType "application/json"
```

Here is the ASP.Net core endpoint definition:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QueueJob([FromBody]BuildJobVM newBuildJob)
    {
        logger.LogDebug("POST request traced");    
    }
```

The problem is the endpoint get's called but the body object newBuildJob is always null. The powershell json contains all the parameters specified in the object BuildJobVM.
Any idea why the posted object is always null?

Comment: Have you tried `[FromBody] string JustATest` to see if you're actually getting anything, or maybe it's a problem with how PS is sending data?

Comment: Is your code formatted like this or just in the questions example? The string terminator of a Here-String `'@` can not be preceeded by whitespace, and in your question it has whitespace to the left..

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you tried to run the powershell script in local machine instead of azure devops ps task, what's the result? We can locate the cause of the issue via running the script locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the value of one of the parameters was string instead of integer, hence the object couldn´t be parsed resulting in a null value.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) via [this button](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.